# Trigger before insert, update before, does not work when I import a csv file

Tags: before-trigger

I have a trigger `before insert`, `update before`, but it does not work when I import a `csv file`. But if I edit and save the record it works.
Any idea?

```
Trigger updateContatoPonto on Ponto__c (before insert, before update) {

Set <Decimal> receberInscricaoNumero = new Set <Decimal> ();

for(Ponto__c pontos : trigger.New)
{
    receberInscricaoNumero.add(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c);
    system.debug(receberInscricaoNumero);
}

Map <Decimal, Contact> matchingcontactsMap = new Map <Decimal, Contact> ();

for (Contact contacts : [Select Id, Inscricao_Numero__c From Contact Where Inscricao_Numero__c IN :receberInscricaoNumero])
{
    matchingcontactsMap.put(contacts.Inscricao_Numero__c, contacts);
}

List <Ponto__c> receivablesToUpdate = new List <Ponto__c> ();
for(Ponto__c pontos : trigger.New)
{
    if (matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c) != null)
    {
       pontos.Contato__c = matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c).Id;
       system.debug(matchingcontactsMap);
    } 
    else {
            pontos.Contato__c = null;
        }
} 
update receivablesToUpdate;
}
```

> If I insert records in Developer Console, works too;

Example,

```
List<Ponto__c> testpontoList = new List<Ponto__c>();        
for(integer i=122;i<125;i++){
    testpontoList.add(new ponto__c(Inscricao_Numero__c = i));
}
insert testpontoList;
```

The `inscricao_numero__c = 123` exists in contact, so the record is updated with `contactid` from `Contact`, but when i import the CSV file, do not update the record.

[image: Exemple insert in console]

[image: map]

[image: DEBUG]

Comment: Check the logs .Looks like all the records in CSV none of them actually match your logic .Make sure to add debug and view logs

Comment: Check that you're inserting exact values in you csv. Decimal values may differ between UI and DB. Try to add setscale to decimals.

Comment: But if I edit and save the record it works.

Comment: As @Mohith mentioned. Try to add system.debug and check what came to SF, what is stored in contact etc.

Comment: Can you explain where to put system.debug in the code? Please? After that I need analyze the debug in the Developer Console ok? sorry um new developer.

Comment: line 10:system.debug(receberInscricaoNumero);
line 18:system.debug(matchingcontactsMap);

Comment: Updated the code, I will try test,

Comment: @IlyaLepesh see! picture,

Comment: Are you mapping fields in dataloader correctly? Do you see INSCRICAO_NUMERO for new records?

Comment: @IlyaLepesh see! picture 2, INSCRICAO_NUMERO  = Credencial

Comment: That screenshot does not look like to me using data loader ? Are you using data loader

Comment: this is import wizard

Comment: @Colonel, do you see new records in SF while importing them, field inscrucao is presented? What is displayed in logs? You can check option debug only, so you'll see only sys.debug

Comment: Please, see, @IlyaLepesh, Mohith Shrivastava, the problem is, when i import by wizard the trigger does not work

Comment: @Coronel Hi there. I've made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/9e4ba169b87d6a17b31a834714c4704d) that may or may not fix your problem. If it does solve your problem, I'll be happy to add it as an answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox tks! i will test!

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, the field is decimal(10,0), see error, Incompatible key type Decimal for Map<Integer,Id>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using import wizard I have following logs:

```
DEBUG|{123.0}
{Id=0033600000MIRZOAA5, Inscricao_Numero__c=123}}
```

So the is no problem in selecting from contact, but we can't get values from map.

You can change key field type to String or use type conversion:

```
if (matchingcontactsMap.get((integer)pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c) != null)
{
    pontos.Contato__c = matchingcontactsMap.get((integer)pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c).Id;
```

Comment: Tks a lot! works! @IlyaLepesh